# How to direct to initial page of Application after pressing the button, i.e. in 'OnPress' ? [Flutter]

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a button, for which I want that when it is pressed, the home page of the app is opened. I have a Web View Plugin. My application is a Web View app, with url as 'www.google.com'.
Here is my code:

```
FlatButton(onPressed: (){ setState(() => WebviewScaffold(url: "http://www.google.com" ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move between your classes you can use:

```
  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => 
    new YouRItinitialPageCass()),);
}
```

But if you just want to go **back** you can use:

```
onPressed: () {Navigator.pop(context);},
```